# impose bounds on influence function values

Tags: r, confidence-interval, estimation, data-transform

I am trying to figure out how to impose bounds on the influence function values (`ifvals`) obtained from an estimator called the incremental propensity score estimator. Briefly, one provides the value `delta`, which is an odds ratio by which propensity score odds at each time point are multiplied. Its utility is that we are unrestricted by the positivity assumption in causal inference. Unfortunately, the estimator does not automatically impose bounds 0 and 1 on binary outcome data, so individuals' `ifvals` can exceed those values, even though I haven't seen the mean exceed them. Why do I want to impose bounds? Because I want to ensure that 95% confidence intervals are also bounded. I planned to construct the confidence intervals on the logit scale and then backtransform, but cannot do that with `ifvals` that are ≤0 and ≥1. Does anyone know how to 1) impose bounds on `ifvals`? and 2) construct the confidence intervals I desire? Code for the package is below followed by code for simulated data.

```
#' @title Estimating effects of incremental propensity score interventions
#'
#' @description \code{ipsi} is used to estimate effects of incremental
#'  propensity score interventions, i.e., estimates of mean outcomes if the odds
#'  of receiving treatment were multiplied by a factor delta.
#'
#' @usage ipsi(y, a, x.trt, x.out, time, id, delta.seq, nsplits, ci_level = 0.95,
#'  progress_bar = TRUE, return_ifvals = FALSE, fit,
#'  sl.lib=c("SL.earth","SL.gam","SL.glm","SL.glmnet","SL.glm.interaction", "SL.mean","SL.ranger","rpart"))
#'
#' @param y Outcome of interest measured at end of study.
#' @param a Binary treatment.
#' @param x.trt Covariate matrix for treatment regression.
#' @param x.out Covariate matrix for outcome regression.
#' @param time Measurement time.
#' @param id Subject identifier.
#' @param delta.seq Sequence of delta increment values for incremental
#'  propensity score intervention.
#' @param nsplits Integer number of sample splits for nuisance estimation. If
#'  \code{nsplits = 1}, sample splitting is not used, and nuisance functions are
#'  estimated n full sample (in which case validity of standard errors and
#'  confidence intervals requires empirical process conditions). Otherwise must
#'  have \code{nsplits > 1}.
#' @param ci_level A \code{numeric} value giving the level (1 - alpha) of the
#'  confidence interval to be computed around the point estimate.
#' @param progress_bar A \code{logical} value indicating whether to print a
#'  customized progress bar as various stages of computation reach completion.
#'  The default is \code{TRUE}, printing a progress bar to inform the user.
#' @param return_ifvals A \code{logical} indicating whether the estimated
#'  observation-level values of the influence function ought to be returned as
#'  part of the output object. The default is \code{FALSE} as these values are
#'  rarely of interest in standard usage.
#' @param fit How nuisance functions should be estimated. Options are "rf" for
#'  random forests via the \code{ranger} package, or "sl" for super learner.
#' @param sl.lib sl.lib algorithm library for SuperLearner.
#' Default library includes "earth", "gam", "glm", "glmnet", "glm.interaction",
#' "mean", "ranger", "rpart.
#'
#' @section Details:
#' Treatment and covariates are expected to be time-varying and measured
#' throughout the course of the study. Therefore if \code{n} is the number of
#' subjects and \code{T} the number of timepoints, then \code{a}, \code{time},
#' and \code{id} should all be vectors of length \code{n}x\code{T}, and
#' \code{x.trt} and \code{x.out} should be matrices with \code{n}x\code{T} rows.
#' However \code{y} should be a vector of length \code{n} since it is only
#' measured at the end of the study. The subject ordering should be consistent
#' across function inputs, based on the ordering specified by \code{id}. See
#' example below for an illustration.
#'
#' @return A list containing the following components:
#' \item{res}{ estimates/SEs and uniform CIs for population means.}
#' \item{res.ptwise}{ estimates/SEs and pointwise CIs for population means.}
#' \item{calpha}{ multiplier bootstrap critical value.}
#'
#' @importFrom stats qnorm as.formula
#' @importFrom ranger ranger
#'
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' n <- 500
#' T <- 4
#'
#' time <- rep(1:T, n)
#' id <- rep(1:n, rep(T, n))
#' x.trt <- matrix(rnorm(n * T * 5), nrow = n * T)
#' x.out <- matrix(rnorm(n * T * 5), nrow = n * T)
#' a <- rbinom(n * T, 1, .5)
#' y <- rnorm(mean=1,n)
#'
#' d.seq <- seq(0.1, 5, length.out = 10)
#'
#' ipsi.res <- ipsi(y, a, x.trt, x.out, time, id, d.seq)
#' @references Kennedy EH. Nonparametric causal effects based on incremental
#' propensity score interventions.
#' \href{https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00211}{arxiv:1704.00211}
#
ipsi2 <- function(y, a, x.trt, x.out, time, id, svywt, delta.seq,
                 nsplits = 2, ci_level = 0.95,
                 progress_bar = TRUE, return_ifvals = FALSE,
                 fit = "rf",
                 sl.lib = c("SL.glm", "SL.mean", "SL.earth", "SL.xgboost", "SL.glmnet")) {
  
  require("SuperLearner")
  require("earth")
  require("rpart")
  require("xgboost")
  require("glmnet")
  
  # setup storage
  ntimes <- length(table(time))
  end <- max(time)
  n <- length(unique(id))
  ynew <- rep(NA, n * ntimes)
  ynew[time == end] <- y
  dat <- data.frame(time = time, id = id, y = ynew, a = a, svywt = svywt)
  k <- length(delta.seq)
  ifvals <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = k)
  est.eff <- rep(NA, k)
  wt <- matrix(nrow = n * ntimes, ncol = k)
  cumwt <- matrix(nrow = n * ntimes, ncol = k)
  rt <- matrix(nrow = n * ntimes, ncol = k)
  vt <- matrix(nrow = n * ntimes, ncol = k)
  x.trt <- data.frame(x.trt)
  x.out <- data.frame(x.out); x.out$a <- a
  
  if (progress_bar) {
    pb <- txtProgressBar(
      min = 0, max = 2 * nsplits * length(delta.seq) + 3,
      style = 3
    )
  }
  
  s <- sample(rep(seq_len(nsplits), ceiling(n / nsplits))[seq_len(n)])
  slong <- rep(s, rep(ntimes, n))
  
  if (progress_bar) {
    pbcount <- 0
  }
  
  for (split in seq_len(nsplits)) {
    if (progress_bar) {
      Sys.sleep(0.1)
      setTxtProgressBar(pb, pbcount)
      pbcount <- pbcount + 1
    }
    
    # fit treatment model
    if (fit=="rf"){
      trtmod <- ranger::ranger(stats::as.formula("a ~ ."),
                               dat = cbind(x.trt, a = dat$a)[slong != split, ])
      dat$ps <- predict(trtmod, data = x.trt)$predictions
    }
    
    if (fit=="sl"){
      trtmod <- SuperLearner(dat$a[slong!=split], x.trt[slong!=split,],
                             newX = x.trt, SL.library = sl.lib, family = binomial)
      dat$ps <- trtmod$SL.predict
    }
    
    for (j in seq_len(k)) {
      if (progress_bar) {
        Sys.sleep(0.1)
        setTxtProgressBar(pb, pbcount)
        pbcount <- pbcount + 1
      }
      delta <- delta.seq[j]
      
      # compute weights
      wt[, j] <- ((delta * dat$a + 1 - dat$a) / (delta * dat$ps + 1 - dat$ps))
      cumwt[, j] <- as.numeric(t(aggregate(wt[, j],
                                           by = list(dat$id),
                                           cumprod
      )[, -1]))
      vt[, j] <- (((1 - delta) * (dat$a * (1 - dat$ps) -
                                  (1 - dat$a) * delta * dat$ps) / delta))
      
      # fit outcome models
      outmod <- vector("list", ntimes)
      rtp1 <- dat$y[dat$time == end]
      if (progress_bar) {
        Sys.sleep(0.1)
        setTxtProgressBar(pb, pbcount)
        pbcount <- pbcount + 1
      }
      for (i in seq_len(ntimes)) {
        t <- rev(unique(dat$time))[i]
        
        # counterfactual case for treatment: A = 1
        newx1 <- x.out[dat$time == t, ]
        newx1$a <- 1
        
        # counterfactual case for no treatment: A = 0
        newx0 <- x.out[dat$time == t, ]
        newx0$a <- 0
        
        if (fit=="rf"){
          outmod[[i]] <- ranger::ranger(stats::as.formula("rtp1 ~ ."),
                                        dat = cbind(x.out,rtp1)[dat$time == t & slong != split, ])
          m1 <- predict(outmod[[i]], data = newx1)$predictions
          m0 <- predict(outmod[[i]], data = newx0)$predictions
        }
        
        if (fit=="sl"){
          print(c(i,j)); flush.console()
          outmod[[i]] <- SuperLearner(rtp1[s!=split],
                                      x.out[dat$time==t & slong!=split,],SL.library = sl.lib,
                                      newX=rbind(newx1,newx0))
          m1 <- outmod[[i]]$SL.predict[1:dim(newx1)[1]]
          m0 <- outmod[[i]]$SL.predict[(dim(newx1)[1]+1):(dim(newx1)[1]+dim(newx0)[1])]
        }
        
        pi.t <- dat$ps[dat$time == t] * ((dat$svywt[dat$time == t])) * (sum(dat$time == t)/(sum(dat$svywt[dat$time == t])))
        rtp1 <- (delta * pi.t * m1 + (1 - pi.t) * m0) /
          (delta * pi.t + 1 - pi.t)
        rt[dat$time == t, j] <- rtp1
      }
      # compute influence function values
      ifvals[s == split, j] <- ((cumwt[, j] * dat$y)[dat$time == end] +
                                  aggregate(cumwt[, j] * vt[, j] * rt[, j],
                                            by = list(dat$id), sum
                                  )[, -1])[s == split]
    }
  }
  
  # compute estimator
  for (j in seq_len(k)) {
    est.eff[j] <- sum(ifvals[, j] * svywt) / sum(svywt)
  }

  # compute asymptotic variance
  ifvals <- ifvals * svywt
  sigma <- sqrt(apply(ifvals, 2, var))
  se <- sigma / sqrt(n)
  ci_norm_bounds <- abs(stats::qnorm(p = (1 - ci_level) / 2))
  eff.ll <- est.eff - ci_norm_bounds * se
  eff.ul <- est.eff + ci_norm_bounds * se
  
  # multiplier bootstrap
  if (progress_bar) {
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    setTxtProgressBar(pb, pbcount)
    pbcount <- pbcount + 1
  }
  
  eff.mat <- matrix(rep(est.eff, n), nrow = n, byrow = TRUE)
  sig.mat <- matrix(rep(sigma, n), nrow = n, byrow = TRUE)
  ifvals2 <- (ifvals - eff.mat) / sig.mat
  nbs <- 10000
  mult <- matrix(2 * rbinom(n * nbs, 1, 0.5) - 1, nrow = n, ncol = nbs)
  maxvals <- sapply(seq_len(nbs), function(col) {
    max(abs(apply(mult[, col] * ifvals2, 2, sum) / sqrt(n)))
  })
  calpha <- quantile(maxvals, ci_level)
  eff.ll2 <- est.eff - calpha * se
  eff.ul2 <- est.eff + calpha * se
  
  if (progress_bar) {
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    setTxtProgressBar(pb, pbcount)
    close(pb)
  }
  
  res <- data.frame(
    increment = delta.seq, est = est.eff, se = se,
    ci.ll = eff.ll2, ci.ul = eff.ul2
  )
  res2 <- data.frame(
    increment = delta.seq, est = est.eff, se = se,
    ci.ll = eff.ll, ci.ul = eff.ul
  )
  
  # output
  if (return_ifvals) {
    return(invisible(list(
      res = res, res.ptwise = res2, ifvals = (ifvals - est.eff)
    )))
  } else {
    return(invisible(list(res = res, res.ptwise = res2, ifvals = ifvals, ifvals2 = ifvals2, est.eff = est.eff)))
  }
}
```

**Simulated data**

I am using a version of the made up data Edward Kennedy provides in this package (thanks for such an awesome method and package!). Here's the code for the simulated data:

```
n <- 500
T <- 4
svywt <- as.integer(rep((rnorm(n, mean = 50, sd = 1)), rep(T, n)))
svywt <- svywt/mean(svywt)
time <- rep(1:T, n)
id <- rep(1:n, rep(T, n))
x.trt <- matrix(rnorm(n * T * 5), nrow = n * T)
x.out <- matrix(rnorm(n * T * 5), nrow = n * T)
a <- rbinom(n * T, 1, .5)
y <- rbinom(n * T, 1, .2)
d.seq <- seq(0.1, 5, length.out = 5)
set.seed(500, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
sl.lib <- c("SL.glm", "SL.mean", "SL.earth", "SL.xgboost", "SL.glmnet")
res1 <- ipsi2(y, a, x.trt, x.out, time, id, svywt, d.seq, fit = "sl", sl.lib = sl.lib)
```

Comment: Quick tip: per [*R Packages*](https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html#import-r), you should **never** include your dependencies via a call to `library()` or its cousin `require()`: *"Use `library(x)` in data analysis scripts...Never use `library()` in a package."* Instead, note each external package in the `Imports` field of your `DESCRIPTION` file;  `usethis::use_package()` automates that. Then qualify your use of functions from that package, via the `pkg::fun()` convention; or use either `@import pkg` for the whole package or `@importFrom pkg fun fun2 ...` for specific functions from that package.

Comment: thanks for the tip! I am not the author of the package, but I will consider your suggestion with my own code.